# Cannot Generate Page Access Token Using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I cannot seem to generate a page access token.  I've tried using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) by selecting "Get Page Access Token" from the User or Page dropdown, but it opens a window with the following error:

[image]

I've also tried sending the following API request but even though it returns a `200 OK` status code, the content is an empty array!

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/{your-user-id}/accounts?access_token={user-access-token}
```

Result:

```
{"data":[]}
```

I've also tried to get the page access token with the following command:

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/<page_id>?access_token=<user_access_token>&fields=access_token"
```

Result:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Object does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permission or reviewable feature, or does not support this operation. This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#page-public-metadata-access for details.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AIx208__9nozhxypMyxZYpy"}}
```

**My user is listed as the admin for this page** and I previously was able to create page access tokens simply by using the Graph API Explorer above.

In the Graph API Explorer, I don't seem to have any such option for  'pages_read_engagement.'

[image]

How can I generate a page access token?

*Note:* I've also asked this question on the Facebook Developer Community Forum but no one has answered yet.  This seems like a simple question so I'm surprised I've not gotten any responses thus far.  https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/911494286473743/

Ref. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens#pagetokens

Comment: Same issue here. No matter what I try, I cannot get it. I get the feeling it has something to do with the Meta Business center change, but that is just a hunch. Did you find any solution eventually?

Answer (score 8):

Ask for the permission `business_management` access permission. There is not a word about this in the docs, but it fixed it for me.

My problem started occurring after I became a full admin in meta business manager.

[image]

Comment: This was changed in an out-of-cycle release and documentation hasn't been updated, but the release notes mention this change. Since Sept 15, 2023 this applied to v17 and later, but applies to all versions since Jan 23, 2024. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/non-versioned-changes/nvc-2023

Answer (score 1):

If you're admin and you've Facebook Page ID of the page you need access token then you can use following API to fetch page access token -

```bash
curl --location --request GET 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/<page_id>?access_token=<user_access_token>&fields=access_token'
```

You can also use Graph API Explorer to fetch the same using user token.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The error I get is `"(#100) Object does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permission or reviewable feature, or does not support this operation. This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages...`

Comment: Try to regenerate user token with required permission by adding missing permission from permissions tab just below user/app token selection. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: The required permission, 'pages_read_engagement' does not seem to be included in the list (screenshot added above).  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Same issue here, cannot get hold of the page token

Answer (score -1):

The problem you are facing is because you did not created Business app on Facebook developer account.

Delete your app and recreate a new Business App then try.

I will work for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).